# I keep getting this error "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" Why?

Tags: ios, swift, ads

Im adding these StartApp interstitial ads and I keep getting an error when I call this function thats in my GameScene. If I call it in my GameViewController it works perfectly and I get no errors but its not working in my GameScene. How would I fix this. Thanks!

//This is the fuction that gives the error.

> self.viewController.startAppAd!.loadAdWithDelegate(viewController.self)

```
//GameViewController.swift

class GameViewController: UIViewController, STADelegateProtocol  {

    var startAppAd: STAStartAppAd?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        startAppAd = STAStartAppAd()

        if let scene = GameScene.unarchiveFromFile("GameScene") as? GameScene {
        // Configure the view.
        let skView = self.view as! SKView
        skView.showsFPS = true
        skView.showsNodeCount = true

        /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
        skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
    }


    // StartApp Ad loaded successfully
    func didLoadAd(ad: STAAbstractAd) {
        println("StartApp Ad had been loaded successfully")
        startAppAd!.showAd()
    }
}

//GameScene.swift
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    var touch: UITouch = touches.first as! UITouch
    var location = touch.locationInNode(self)
    var node = self.nodeAtPoint(location)

    if node.name == "levelone" {

    self.viewController.startAppAd!.loadAdWithDelegate(viewController.self)
}
```

Comment: You can easily tell that startAppAd is nil when you're trying to call your function.

Comment: Where in GameScene.swift are you calling it? More info please, and Please fix your format in the question.

Comment: I will update the code its in my touchesBegan.

Comment: SKScene doesnt have a property called viewController, you must've added it yourself and forgot to add self to it.

Comment: var viewController = GameViewController() I added this in my GameScene so I could call the function from the GameViewController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GameViewController` creates the `GameScene` during `viewDidLoad` but you are never assigning it to the `GameScene` for referencing

You say you have `var viewController = GameViewController()` in `GameScene` but thats not the same instance which created the scene in the first place.

You can add this to your `viewDidLoad`

`scene.viewController = self` to ensure that the instance with an non-nil `startAppAd` object is the one you are referencing.

Comment: what do I declare scene as. I get an error that says unresloved identifier.

Comment: have you read your own code? `if let scene = GameScene.unarchiveFromFile("GameScene") as? GameScene {` inside that scope . But taking a closer look that snippet you provide makes no sense as you never do anything with `scene`

Comment: Yes i get what your saying I forgot to add a line of code. Im using the scene like this scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill. It works now btw. Thank you!

Comment: I have one more question/ When I press on my level to activate the ad a second time that error comes back. Why does that happen?

Comment: Same reason as the first time . Either explicitly or implicitly your reference has gone to nil. Figure out why. It's the danger or advantage of force unwrapping vars. you can always tell when something is nil

Answer (score 0):

You're force unwrapping `startAppAd` (using the ! operator) which tells the compiler “I know that this optional definitely has a value; please use it.”. However in your code `startAppAd` is presumedly nil. Therefore the crash.

I suggest you take a basic tour and read Apple's ["Swift Programming Language"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html)